# Name on Check in QuickBooks SDK

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc, qbxml

I have a customer requirement to export the checks written in QuickBooks into a specific format because their bank allows fraud prevention by uploading a file and they verify the name on the check against what you give them before clearing it.

I looked at the QuickBooks SDK (we use the XML to communicate in general) and It references a field on the check called PayeeEntityRef with a FullName property, but typically in QuickBooks that data structure would indicate what the entity is called, not what appears on the check (Vendors have a NameOnCheck property, for example, which can be something other than their name).

Without coding up multiple test cases to demonstrate QuickBooks behavior here, does anyone have experience with getting the name as it was printed on the check? What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's somewhat possible to get what you are wanting, but there are going to be some hiccups that you'll need to let you client know about. The main problem being that there's no way to retrieve the actual name printed on the check.

You would first need to query for the Checks/Bill Payment - Checks for the bank account. Then, using the PayeeEntityRef (I would use the ListID component) figure out which "List" the entity is on; Customer, Vendor, Employee, or Other. I don't know of any way to tell which list the PayeeEntityRef is from other than doing a query for each of the lists.

If the PayeeEntityRef is a Vendor or Employee, then you can retrieve the NameOnCheck value. The only thing you would need to keep in mind is that if the NameOnCheck has been modified AFTER the check was printed, the names will not match.

If the PayeeEntityRef is a Customer or Other name, then you have to do a little bit more. The value that QuickBooks uses for the printed name is based on what fields are filled out for the customer record. It first will use the CompanyName field if it is not null. Next, it will try to use the First/Middle/LastName fields, if they are not null. Finally, it will use the Name field as a last resort. Keep in mind that this is not the FullName field, just the Name field.

I haven't tested this with an "Other" name, as I have my clients try not to use that list, but I would imagine it's similar to how Customers work.